# PayPal webhook signature verification in C#

Tags: c#, paypal

I have a C# application that receives webhook notifications from PayPal and I want to verify the signature as described in PayPal docs:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-types

The code snippet in the docs is for Java, not C#. The first thing I don't know is in which format the CRC32 should be appended (decimal, hex, ???). I have tried several variants and I have following code so far, always with `VerifyData()` returning `false`:

```
string transmissionSig = HttpContext.Request.Headers["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG"];
string transmissionId = HttpContext.Request.Headers["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID"];
string transmissionTime = HttpContext.Request.Headers["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME"];
string signatureAlgorithm = HttpContext.Request.Headers["PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO"]; //signatureAlgorithm == "SHA256withRSA"
string certUrl = HttpContext.Request.Headers["PAYPAL-CERT-URL"]; 

uint crc = calculateCrc32(eventBody);

string expectedSignature = String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", transmissionId, transmissionTime, webhookId, crc);

string certData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(certUrl);

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(getBytes(certData));

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;

byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(transmissionSig);

byte[] expectedBytes = getBytes(expectedSignature);

bool verified = rsa.VerifyData(expectedBytes, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I use this class for CRC calculation: https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/blob/master/CSharp/DamienG.Library/Security/Cryptography/Crc32.cs

Example eventBody (from webhook simulator):

```
{"id":"WH-2WR32451HC0233532-67976317FL4543714","create_time":"2014-10-23T17:23:52Z","resource_type":"sale","event_type":"PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED","summary":"A successful sale payment was made for $ 0.48 USD","resource":{"id":"80021663DE681814L","create_time":"2014-10-23T17:22:56Z","update_time":"2014-10-23T17:23:04Z","amount":{"total":"0.48","currency":"USD"},"payment_mode":"ECHECK","state":"completed","protection_eligibility":"ELIGIBLE","protection_eligibility_type":"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE","clearing_time":"2014-10-30T07:00:00Z","parent_payment":"PAY-1PA12106FU478450MKRETS4A","links":[{"href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/80021663DE681814L","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/80021663DE681814L/refund","rel":"refund","method":"POST"},{"href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1PA12106FU478450MKRETS4A","rel":"parent_payment","method":"GET"}]},"links":[{"href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-2WR32451HC0233532-67976317FL4543714","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-2WR32451HC0233532-67976317FL4543714/resend","rel":"resend","method":"POST"}]}
```

And it's CRC that I'm getting and appending to expectedSignature: `3561502039`

Comment: Can you add the code for your `calculateCrc32` method? Something looks wrong there, way too many )'s, it wouldn't compile. Also add the code where you calculate the `crcStr`.

Comment: Just a heads up, but the [PayPal .NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/webhook-event-validation) is preparing for an upcoming release that includes webhook event validation.  The CRC32 value should be a decimal value (your code looks to be correct, but it'd be good to know what `calculateCrc32()` is doing, as @RonBeyer suggested).  Also, instead of "SHA256", try "SHA1" for the hash algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for comment @RonBeyer. I updated the question with details about the CRC and changed the hash to SHA1. Maybe there's indeed a problem with the CRC or the input body, beacause an online CRC tool gives me different results when I put the eventBody there: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/crc/

Comment: Looking forward to the new SDK @JasonZ :)

Answer (score 0):

you should get algorithm from the header in stead of hard-coding it. SHA256 is the currently supported algorithm I think.