# How to verify PayPal webhook Signature in C#?

Tags: c#, paypal

I have a C# Application that receives a Webhook notification from PayPal, I want to to verify the Webhook signature.

I already found 2 questions related to the same issue without a clear working solution

[PayPal webhook signature verification in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967922/paypal-webhook-signature-verification-in-c-sharp)
[How to verify PayPal Webhook signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61651765/how-to-verify-paypal-webhook-signature)

```
public static bool Validate(X509Certificate2 x509Certificate, WebhookSignature webhookSignature)
    {
        bool isValid = false;

        try
        {
            byte[] webhookBodyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(webhookSignature.webhook_event);

            uint crc32 = Crc32CAlgorithm.Compute(webhookBodyByte);

            var expectedSignature = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", webhookSignature.transmission_id, webhookSignature.transmission_time, webhookSignature.webhook_id, crc32);
            byte[] expectedSignatureBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expectedSignature);

            byte[] signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(webhookSignature.transmission_sig);

            using (RSA rsa = x509Certificate.GetRSAPublicKey())
            {
                isValid = rsa.VerifyData(expectedSignatureBytes, signatureBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

rsa.VerifyDat returns always false,I think the problem is with calculating the CRC32 value.
"as mentioned in the 2 duplicated questions"
can someone please shed some light on this issue?

request body:

```
{"id":"WH-9UD89617J3011950R-48P38622S7224850U","event_version":"1.0","create_time":"2021-04-12T13:48:33.815Z","resource_type":"checkout-order","resource_version":"2.0","event_type":"CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED","summary":"An order has been approved by buyer","resource":{"create_time":"2021-04-12T13:47:55Z","purchase_units":[{"reference_id":"default","amount":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"300.00"},"payee":{"email_address":"sb-6g4h15347490@business.example.com","merchant_id":"6WHMHKSMV4T4E","display_data":{"brand_name":"ieQ Shop"}},"shipping":{"name":{"full_name":"test buyer"},"address":{"address_line_1":"ESpachstr. 1","admin_area_2":"Freiburg","admin_area_1":"Empty","postal_code":"79111","country_code":"DE"}}}],"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/2PY82104UY468500C","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/2PY82104UY468500C","rel":"update","method":"PATCH"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/2PY82104UY468500C/capture","rel":"capture","method":"POST"}],"id":"2PY82104UY468500C","intent":"CAPTURE","payer":{"name":{"given_name":"test","surname":"buyer"},"email_address":"rasheed.alsamawi-buyer@gmail.com","payer_id":"WQRMLHUWJA7H4","address":{"address_line_1":"Strasse Nummer X","address_line_2":"Strasse Nummer X","admin_area_2":"admin 2","admin_area_1":"admin 1","postal_code":"12345","country_code":"DE"}},"status":"APPROVED"},"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-9UD89617J3011950R-48P38622S7224850U","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-9UD89617J3011950R-48P38622S7224850U/resend","rel":"resend","method":"POST"}]}
```

request headers:
[image: request headers]

Thanks

Comment: Is your request getting a good response status of 200 OK?  If you are getting an status 400/500 error that you first need to get a good response before you try to test CRC of the body.

Comment: I am getting a response for sure, otherwise I would have gotten an exception.
webhookSignature contains the values coming from the successful PayPal request that include the algorithm, time, signature etc.

Comment: I don't always trust the exceptions.  A 400/500 error is not an exception (depending on how you code is handling the status).  It is a response with no data in the body.  With no body you would fail the CRC check.

Comment: I updated the question, showing the incoming post from PayPal.

Comment: Where is the variable webhookSignature.webhook_event coming from?  You are getting the entire message from an EVENT?  What portion of the message is the signature using? It looks like you are getting the signature of the Transmitting request while you are asking to verify the incoming post.  So is this code in the client checking the send request or in the server checking the received request.  Doesn't make a difference, but just like to know.

Answer (score 2):

I also spent a lot of time to figure out.
But when I used Crc32 calculation from [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/ec14d73c35b319f2072f65b755a802d653b8133a/Source/SDK/Util/Crc32.cs) it verified request!
This Crc32 looks strange but it works!

Comment: I am getting the same CRC32 calculation result from `Crc32Algorithm` and your provided link `ComputeChecksum` method.